# iOS: Assigning new Window in iOS app is showing black screen for a moment?

Tags: ios, routes, uiwindow

I am trying to solve app routing problem. I need to navigate to some screen when user tap on some notification or click on any button (for eg **X**) from anywhere in app (might be in middle of stack of navigation controller or on presenting controller) and I need to open the same screen always.

My app also have Tabbar and each tab of tab bar have navigation controller. I am trying to call my window method to recreate the window which subsequently creates Tabbar and all initial controller and route to path. But I am facing a black screen while doing so.

For test, whenever I changed path I am sending empty window but still seeing the black screen.

[image: This piece of code is observing path change in an app]

Here I am assigning window. It is on main thread.

[image: Window Assigning]

Comment: I don't think creating a new window is suitable for your case. How about changing `rootViewController` of the existing window?

Comment: Why it is not suitable? I tried to make a demo and I can change the window without black screen. Can you help me with what UI problem I am facing here? I will try changing rootViewController though.